# iPhone: transfer audio from Whatsapp to Music library

Tags: iphone, music, whatsapp.app

I'm using an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1. I've been sent some songs(*)  via Whatsapp, and I'd like to copy them to my music library in the iPhone, so that I can listen to them, add them to my playlists, etc., but I can't find the way. Here are my limitations:

- Whatsapp only offers the option to share the songs via Whatsapp or
  via email.
- My iPhone is synced to my desktop computer, which I don't
  have with me. I have a Macbook with me (OS X 10.8.5), but I don't
  want to sync the iPhone to it, because it will wipe everything in my
  phone.
- I don't use iCloud, nor I have it activated in any of my devices… though I could do so, if I have to.

What can I do? If the solution is to use iCloud, how would I do so without wiping or syncing the rest of the contents in my phone? (I have waaay more than the free 5 Gb. in an iCloud account).

(*) Non-pirated songs!!! They are a demo from a musician friend of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the share button and send it to yourself via email. Then, open your mail in iPhone and it will download the song. Long press on the name of the song until it asks which application to open in.

There, you can open that song in your preferred app (but not not the iPhone music library) like i downloader, and also  download it to your OC from the emails.

Comment: Sorry there is no `share` option in whatsapp audio. Only `forward` option that is meant for within whatsapp contacts.